# is there any good implementation to the RSA in arduino ? c language

Tags: library, c, cryptography

I need a good implementation to the RSA algorithm that works on Arduino Mega with key size 1024. The code will run on Arduino IDE.

The project idea simply is that an Android app sends an encrypted message (with RSA encryption algorithm) through Bluetooth, to Arduino Mega (the Arduino Mega will receive the message throw a Bluetooth module), and then the Arduino Mega will decrypt the message.

The Android SDK provides a good RSA encryption class but on the Arduino side, I haven't found any RSA libraries provided by the Arduino company. 
So I need a good implementation for the RSA encryption algorithm in the C language to work on the Arduino. Any help?

Comment: [BearSSL](https://bearssl.org/) should probably be able to do the job, but RSA isn't part of the intended public interface...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I saw BearSSL as you suggested but I couldn't separate using the RSA alone. do you have any  BearSSL implementation for just encrypt a message using RSA?